# Creating a EDT (Eastern Daylight Time) - timestamp

Tags: php

I tried using the php function below to accomplish this, however, it returns a mounain time, timestamp. I was wondering if someone can help me understand how I change time zones, or if someone can help me correct this to EDT?

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set it locally in the script itself, by using the date_default_timezone_set() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Or you can change it in your php.ini file, if you look for the line:

```
date.timezone
```

Edit: Here is a list of supported timezones, if you're not sure what yours should be called:
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the reply. For some reason it is still returning the incorrect date. I set it to New York using the method you advised, and it seems to simply subtract 6 hours from the correct New York time...?

Comment: Hmm. It works alright for me when I try it. Did you make sure to include the underscore in "New_York"?: date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

Comment: I fixed it, I ended using "US/Pacific", that solved the problem. ;) I appreciate your help, you got me on the right track.