# php EDT/EST time convert

Tags: php

My code is the following:

```
<?php

function my_time($zone,$dst){
  if ($dst=='on') {
    // bellow codes will return time date when DST is on/EDT time
    $dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($zone));
    $dst_on = $dateTime->format("d-m-Y h:i A");
    return $dst_on;
  }elseif ($dst=='off') {
    // bellow codes will return time date when DST is off/EST time
    $dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($zone));
    $dst_off = $dateTime->format("d-m-Y h:i A");
    return $dst_off.' (Wrong output, i need DST off/EST output here! Please help)'; // Please help me to return dst off / EST time here
  }
}

echo my_time('America/New_York','off');

?>
```

I want correct output when passing `off` parameter to `my_time` function. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to docs there is no way to turn off DST and it should not be done**

However, I think something like this might work:

```
function my_time($zone, $dst = true) {

    $dateTime = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone($zone));

    if ($dst) {
        $dateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('US/Pacific'));
    }

    return $dateTime->format('d-m-Y, h:i A');
}

echo my_time('America/New_York', false);
```

I changed your code around a little bit, but from what I saw on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593056/creating-a-edt-eastern-daylight-time-timestamp) using 'US/Pacific' should make the time EDT. I also changed the DST to a bool which makes it a little nicer to read